# How to achieve parallelization in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

I am converting a Spark dataframe to an Array and then iterating over the array to execute a spark job

```
    val suppliersList = mutable.MutableList[SuppliersCompany]()
    val df_arr: Array[SuppliersCompany] = df.collect()

     for (suppliersCompany <- df_arr) {
      suppliersList+=UnifiedDedupeHelper.applyDedupe(suppliersCompany)
    }
```

I have almost 600000 rows in the dataframe and the sparkjob is taking some time,So it is taking a lot of time to complete all the iterations.
I have also tried Parallel Collection in scala but that didn't help much.

```
 val df_arr: ParArray[SuppliersCompany] = df.collect().par

    df_arr.foreach{
      suppliersCompany=>suppliersList+=UnifiedDedupeHelper.applyDedupe(suppliersCompany)
    }
```

Is there any other way to parallelize the iteration to reduce the time.

Comment: Why collect it into a serial **Scala** collection, instead of continue using the **Spark** framework to do the expensive computation?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Because you can't do other transformation inside spark map, that would raise a nullpointerexception.

Comment: Ah, sorry for not understanding the question. It may help if you can share a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem.